# serving PIE.htc file on developer server visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, iis

Is it possible to serve on developer server on visual studio 2010 PIE.htc file ?

Infortunately PIE.htc doesnt work when I try to run my web application on local developer server

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

It needs to run on a server, yes. Whether this is a local or production server doesn't matter. You need to ensure you have [the correct path](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/css3-pie-couple-of-gotchas/) for it to work though.